# Quickly Accessible MathJax Help

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, help-center

I recently had the problem of encoding big brackets in a formula in my question "[Functions that Calculate their $L_p$ Norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173107/functions-that-calculate-their-l-p-norm)" and, I could find nothing under "How to Format > MathJax equations", as the link brought up LaTex encodings which didn't work for MathJax.

As I am not a MathJax wizzard, I was happy to see, that meanwhile someone jumped in and fixed the respective formula with "\Big(" and "\Big)" which I had not seen.

Based on that "experience" I would like to know, why the formatting help for formulas doesn't link to something that is dedicated to MathJax.
Links to good (i.e. compact and well-structured) online-resources would also be a great help.

Comment: Could you please describe the part of the documentation your refer to more precisely. I am not sure what you mean. Meanwhile, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @quid the link I used, was http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node21.html#SECTION00084000000000000000 wich I reached via the orange "MathJax Help" link, that appears, when editing a question; of course most things also work in MathJax, but not all. I'd suggest, the MathJax Help would link to the stackexchange question, you pointed me to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I now found it in the grey box to the right. I agree that this seems a bit too general a link.

Comment: just found a quite helpful link http://www.calculatorium.com/mathjax-quick-start-tutorial

Comment: @MartinSleziak good idea to forward a request to MathJax

Comment: I just found another nice [online documentation](http://www.martinkeefe.com/math/mathjax3)

Comment: Related: [FAQ on typesetting of formulae hard to find](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2957)

Comment: Some links are collected in this answer: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763#3765) I don't think I any one of them is optimal, but let's hope that a few users will join in and other some additional useful links. (Then everybody can choose the one which seems most useful for them.)

Comment: It's actually possible for CMs to update the URL that the "MathJax help" link (at the bottom of the LaTeX section of the `/editing-help` page) points to. [See this post on MSE for more info about updating the "MathJax help" link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288209/335251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com), the ["What topics can I ask about here"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the Help Center links directly to [a meta.math.SE post with a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as well as [some other useful links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

We might be able to steal it, or link to it.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the comments under the question, but I will point out it also here that now there is a post with "intro to MathJax" also on this site: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763) I'd say that probably the tutorial on Mathematics Meta is probably not optimal, being too long for a person who encounters TeX syntax for the first time. See also the comments under this answer: [FAQ on typesetting of formulae hard to find](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2957#2958)