# One number on top of another with mathjax?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Probably a simple question, but how can I write my script in mathjax to show one number on top of another and with a minus sign in the left side?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Some basics about alignment, tables, arrays and similar stuff are mentioned also in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) on Mathematics Meta. A few other useful MathJax-related resources are mentioned in [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

$\begin{eqnarray*} & 682 \\ -&426 \\ \hline \end{eqnarray*}$

`$\begin{eqnarray*} & 682 \\ -&426 \\ \hline \end{eqnarray*}$`

For general $\LaTeX$ questions see [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The tex.SE community strongly discourages MathJax-related questions, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Good to know, anyway I'm not sure whether the OP intended to ask about MathJax specifically

Comment: I have edited your post so that the source code is displayed too. (Feel free to rollback if you prefer not to have it there. But some users might not know how to display source for rendered MathJax, so possibly for such users this might be useful.)

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen right, I meant it only as an addition to your answer.